# How to convert object to stream?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I want to convert the object to a stream in xamarin UWP.

Example:

Button button=new Button();

I want to convert button to a stream.

Anyone, please suggest me?

Comment: why would you ever need to convert a control to a stream?

Comment: I want to save the stream to an image.

Comment: that's fine but that has nothing to do with a button, you want to save an image from a stream to an Image object.

Comment: I want to get the stream of the control to save it in an image. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: you can use image context for views but I don't think you can do it for buttons.

Comment: You want to capture an image of the Button (ie, screenshot it)?.  That has nothing to do with converting to a stream.

Comment: Any other way? My requirement is, I am having the custom view and I want to get the stream of the custom view. So I can use the stream to save the view as  image or PDF